# Reac leaflet TileLayer not serving local tiles in png format

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, offline, react-leaflet

I am using react leaflet and I wanted to be able to use offline maps. Hence I downloaded tiles I was interested in, convert them into png and save them locally. But when I use this code :
 [OpenStreetMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ1kc.png) contributors'
          url="local.mbtiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
I receive error: 1614.png:1 GET http://localhost:8080/local.mbtiles/12/3635/1614.png 404 (Not Found). Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you mean you compressed your PNG tiles into an MBTiles file, or do you have a "local.mbtiles" folder?

Comment: I have a local.mbtiles folder with png images in it

Comment: Assuming you do have the path to these tiles, it seems to me that all that is left is ensuring you serve your tiles as static assets (in both dev and production environments)